# Add class to siblings when Component clicked in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, components

I'm working on building my portfolio using React.js. In one section, I have four components laid out in a grid. What I want to do achieve is when one component is clicked, a css class is added to the siblings of this component so that their opacity is reduced and only the clicked component remains. In jQuery, it would be something like $('.component').on('click', function(){ $(this).siblings.addClass('fadeAway')}). How can I achieve this effect? Here is my code, thanks in advance for any and all help!

```
class Parent extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {fadeAway: false}
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick(){
    //Add class to siblings
  }
  render(){
    const array = ["Hello", "Hi", "How's it going", "Good Times"]
    return(
      array.map(function(obj, index){
        <Child text={obj} key={index} onClick={() => this.handleClick} />
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working example for this problem could look something like this, with a marginally more complex initialization array:

```
class Parent extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      elements: [
        {
          id: "hello",
          text: "Hello",
          reduced: false,
        },

        {
          id: "hi",
          text: "Hi",
          reduced: false,
        }

        {
          id: "howsItGoing"
          text: "How's it going",
          reduced: false,
        }

        {
          id: "goodTimes",
          text: "Good Times",
          reduced: false,
        }
      ],
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(e){
    // copy elements from state
    const elements = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(elements));
    const newElements = elements.map(element => {
      if (element.id === e.target.id) {
        element.reduced = false;
      } else {
        element.reduced = true;
      }
    });


    this.setState({
      elements: newElements,
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      this.state.elements.map(function(obj, index){
        <Child
          id={obj.id}
          text={obj.text}
          reduced={obj.reduced}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => this.handleClick} />
      });
    );
  }
}
```

Then you would just add a ternary, like so, to the `Child` component:

```
<Child
  id={this.props.id}
  className={this.props.reduced ? "reduced" : ""} />
```

This adds a bit more boilerplate than other examples, but it's extremely brittle to tie business logic to the text inside a component, and a stronger solution requires a stronger piece of identification, like an ID or class on the rendered DOM element. This solution also, if you so wish, easily allows you to expand your logic so that more than one element can remain at maximum opacity at once.

Comment: This solution actually helped the most. At first it seemed a bit robust for what I was doing, but you really explained it well and it make total sense to me now. I had to tweak the handleClick function a bit, and didn't need to use JSON.parse, but the overall concept worked and I achieved my end goal. Thank you!! @furkle

Comment: @IanSpringer Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

I would simply store in state index of selected item, and then pass `fadeAway` prop into Child component defined as

```
fadeAway={this.state.selectedIndex !== index}
```

After that you only need to set a `fade-away` class in Child based on `this.prop.fadeAway` and define necessary CSS rules.

Here is how it could look in your case:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {selectedIndex: null}
  }
  handleClick (selectedIndex) {
    this.setState({ selectedIndex })
  }
  render () {
    const array = ["Hello", "Hi", "How's it going", "Good Times"]
    return (
      <div>
        {array.map((obj, index) => {
          const faded = this.state.selectedIndex && this.state.selectedIndex !== index
          return <Child 
            text={obj} 
            fadeAway={faded}
            key={index} 
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)} />
        })}
      </div>  
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <h2
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
        className={this.props.fadeAway ? 'fade-away' : ''}>
        {this.props.text}
      </h2>  
    ) 
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.body
);
```

```css
.fade-away {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be pretty close. However, when the page renders, I want all components to have a full opacity. When one is clicked, the others should THEN lose their opacity. This solution sets one component as active on page load, when they should all be active until one is clicked. Any advice?

Comment: @IanSpringer Sure, just make default `selectedIndex` as `null` and check for it in `const faded = this.state.selectedIndex && this.state.selectedIndex !== index`. Check the demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using using a toggle variable :

```
handleClick(){
  this.setState({fadeAway} => ({
    fadeAway: ! fadeAway
  )};
}
...
<Child
  text={obj}
  key={index}
  onClick={() => this.handleClick}
  className={this.state.fadeAway? 'class1' : 'class2'}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution appears to toggle the class of the targeted component. I need to add a new class to the siblings of the clicked component.

Answer (score 0):

I perfer use state like `currentWord` to save the word was clicked in Parent component, presudo code is like below:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      fadeAway: false,
      currentWord: ''
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick(currentWord){
    this.setState({
      currentWord: currentWord,
    });
  }
  render(){
    const array = ["Hello", "Hi", "How's it going", "Good Times"]
    const currentWord = this.state.currentWord;
    return(
      array.map(function(obj, index){
        <Child currentWord={currentWord} text={obj} key={index} onClick={() => this.handleClick} />
      })
    )
  }
}
```

And in Child component

```
class Child extends Component {
  // some other code

  handleClick(e) {
    this.props.handleClick(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const isSelected = this.props.text === this.props.currentWord;
    // use isSelected to toggle className

    <div
      onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
    >{this.props.text}
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: You're passing the prop as `currentWord` but referencing it within the child component as `CurrentWord`.